# Textbox values are cleared after function ends (Issue): JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below code to set fullName value, logic works but after it sets the value all the textbox values are cleared. I need overcome this issue.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {

$('#check').click(function() {

if ( $('#city').val() == '' )
{
    alert('Empty!!!');
}
else
{
 $('#fullName').val("hi");
}
 });
});

</script>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
City: <input type="text" name="city" id="city"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
Full name: <input type="text" name="fullName" id="fullName"><br>
Phone number: <input type="text" name="Last" value="Mouse"><br>

<button id="check">Check</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PreventDefault()` to cancel postback, becouse your button does not have type so HTML put the default behavior like submit, try:

```
    $('#check').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if ( $('#city').val() == '' )
          {
            alert('Empty!!!');
          }
          else
          {
            $('#fullName').val("hi");
          }
   });
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f5zth21u/)

Answer (score 3):

By default a button within a form but with no type is a submit button. My guess is you are actually submitting the form when you click the button, and the inputs are 'cleared' because a new page is loading.

Try adding `type="button"` to your button.

```
<button id="check" type="button">Check</button>
```